# Combat advantage with ranged attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranged-attack, conditions, combat-advantage

Just curious if ranged attacks gain combat advantage the same way melee attacks would from circumstances that would normally grant. In example, from status effects such as dazed or restrained. I couldn't find a clarification except for prone targets. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Combat Advantage works with ranged attacks.

Combat Advantage *doesn't care* about ranged or melee or bursts or whatever else. Any kind of attack will give you the +2 attack bonus versus that target, as long as you can see them. No part of the CA rules are specified as melee-only.

Conditions such as Blinded, Dazed and Restrained say "the creature grants combat advantage" (in Rules Compendium p229 onwards; the PHB instead says "you grant combat advantage"). That's to everyone; there's no "to melee attackers" phrase.